# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth\access()

Tags: laravel

**After inserting credentials for login, I got this below error in Laravel 6.16.1**

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth\access()

Comment: We're unable to help your issue if you don't post any code from routes.php and Auth.php

Comment: I used this code in my  dashboard.blade.php file  -- @if(access()->user()->hasRole('Administrator')).

Answer (score 0):

What that error is saying is that Laravel did not find the method you presume to have declared inside class `App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Auth`. Your login method is not named `access`.

If it is so still, you probably want to run `php artisan config:cache` and `composer du`